# Two questions about diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

1. Let A = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 4\\0 & 3 & -4\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$. Is the matrix A diagonalizable?  If so find a matrix P that diagonalizes A. Can you write A as a
   linear combination of rank 1 matrices formed from its eigenvectors? Determine the
   eigendecomposition $A = PΛP^{-1}$.
2. A = $\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 & 0\\1 & 2 &1\\0&1&3\end{bmatrix}$. Is the matrix A diagonalizable?  If so find a matrix P that orthogonally diagonalizes A. Can you write A as a linear combination of rank 1 matrices formed from its eigenvectors? (Note that A is real symmetric so that you do not have to compute the inverse of P).

My solution attempts:

1. det(λI - A) = $\begin{vmatrix}λ - 1 & -1 & -4\\0 & λ - 3 &4\\0&0&λ + 1\end{vmatrix}$ = (λ -1) (λ -3) (λ + 1) = 0

$λ_{1}$ = 1, $λ_{2}$ = 3, $λ_{3}$ = -1

($λ_{1}I - A)x_{1}$ = 0

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 & -4\\0 & -2 &4\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}x_{11}\\x_{12}\\x_{13}\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0 \\0\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}x_{11}\\x_{12}\\x_{13}\end{bmatrix}$ = $x_{11} \begin{bmatrix}1\\0 \\0\end{bmatrix}$

It follows that $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0 \\0\end{bmatrix}$ is a basis for the eigenspace of A corresponding to $λ_{1}$ = 1.

In a similar way, I found other two basis vectors as $\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\1 \\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}-2/5\\1 \\1\end{bmatrix}$, and I got $P = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1/2 & -2/5\\0 & 1 & 1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$. Then my $P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1/2 & 9/10\\0 & 1 & -1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$. And I said A's left-multiplication by $P^{-1}$ and right-multiplication by $P (P^{-1}AP)$ gives the diagonal matrix Λ that is similar to A. I found Λ as $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 3 & 0\\0&0&21/5\end{bmatrix}$. Then I said that if we multiply both sides of the equation $P^{-1}AP = Λ$ by $P$ from the left and by $P^{-1}$ from the right we get $PP^{-1}APP^{-1} = PΛP^{-1} = A$ and that this is the eigendecomposition of A. Here is my first question: Do you think I understood and did correctly what the asker wanted me to do by saying "Determine the eigendecomposition $A = PΛP^{-1}$."?

2. I started in the same manner and I got three eigenvectors as

   $\begin{bmatrix}x_{11}\\x_{12}\\x_{13}\end{bmatrix}$ = $x_{12} \begin{bmatrix}0\\1 \\0\end{bmatrix}$,

   $\begin{bmatrix}x_{21}\\x_{22}\\x_{23}\end{bmatrix}$ = $x_{21} \begin{bmatrix}1\\1 \\1\end{bmatrix}$ and

   $\begin{bmatrix}x_{31}\\x_{32}\\x_{33}\end{bmatrix}$ = $x_{33} \begin{bmatrix}1\\-2 \\1\end{bmatrix}$.

I said A is not diagonalizable since the eigenvectors are not linearly independent.

Here is my second question: What the hell does the sentence "Can you write A as a linear combination of rank 1 matrices formed from its eigenvectors?" mean?

Comment: As to 2, why don't start with the same equation $\det(\lambda I - A) = 0$?

Comment: I did start with the same equation. I just didn't write it there, I wrote "I started in the same manner" instead. :)

Comment: Something must have gone wrong in during your "in the same manner", because $(0,1,0)$ is clearly not an eigenvector!

Comment: Your last eigenvector for the first matrix is wrong (slightly).  That's why your diagonal matrix doesn't have the eigenvalues along the diagonal.

Comment: @Kerem The first eigenvector for your second matrix is wrong, too.  Be careful when you calculate these.

Comment: Hint: both matrices are diagonalizable

Comment: @Bye_World, thank you so much. You've been very helpful today. :)

Comment: @Amzoti I'm too lazy to calculate these by hand, but Mathematica says they both can be diagonalized (by actual diagonal matrices, not a JNF -- AKA the Jordan blocks are all $1\times 1$). :)

Comment: @Amzoti Well, write up an answer, then, because like I said, I'm too lazy to calculate these by hand (and then type up those calculations to boot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete answer would be quite involved here; maybe I'll have the time later.  However, I just wanted to address that last question about the combination of rank-1 matrices:

Note that the second matrix $A$ is symmetric, which means that we'll be able to diagonalize it orthogonally.  That is, we can write $A = UDU^T$ where $D$ is diagonal and $U$ is orthogonal so that $U^{-1} = U^T$ and, equivalently, the columns of $U$ are an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A$.

So, we can write
$$
A = \pmatrix{u_1&u_2&u_3}\pmatrix{\lambda_1\\&\lambda_2\\&&\lambda_3}
\pmatrix{u_1^T\\u_2^T\\u_3^T}
$$
with columns $u_i \in \Bbb R^n$ forming an orthonormal basis and $\lambda_i \in \Bbb R$.  By block matrix multiplication, we can rewrite this as
$$
A = \lambda_1 u_1 u_1^T + \lambda_2 u_2u_2^T + \lambda_3 u_3 u_3^T
$$
That is, we can rewrite $A$ as a linear combination of the rank $1$ matrices formed from its eigenvectors.

Comment: I tried and saw that it's not possible for the matrix in the first question to be rewritten as A=λ1u1uT1+λ2u2uT2+λ3u3uT3. Could you tell me why?

Comment: Most matrices cannot be written in this way.  In general, this is possible if and only if the matrix satisfies $A^*A = AA^*$.  In particular, if an upper-triangular matrix can be written in this way, it must be diagonal.  This statement is equivalent to the "spectral theorem".

Comment: And what about my first question. What does the asker want me to do saying "Determine the eigendecomposition"?

Comment: The expression $P\Lambda P^{-1}$ is called the "eigendecomposition" of $A$.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I mean why that sentence is there? What is it supposed to make me do?

Comment: I think it just adds a bit to the sentence "If so, find a matrix P that diagonalizes A", so as to say, "also: find the $\Lambda$ that matches this $P$".

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your great help.